# Change Project Title using Macros in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have created a roll-up Master Project using a VBA macro that grabs all MS project files in a given directory and adds them to my Master Project file. Everything works well but the title these subtasks get added as uses the Project Title (found in File->Info->Project Information->Advanced Properties->Title) instead of the Filename.

I will not be the only person creating these files so I can't guarantee the Title is accurate. What I would like to do is, using a macro, every time a MS Project file is opened it checks if the Title is different than the Filename and if so sets the Title to whatever the Filename is. My issue is, I cannot find a property of the Project object or a method that allows me to access the Project Title. Can anyone help out with how I might accomplish this.

An alternative solution would also be to add the Projects to my Master Project using the Filename instead of the Title but I also haven't figured out how I can accomplish that. To add the projects as subtasks I loop through all .mpp files in a given direction using the following line:

```
ConsolidateProjects Filenames:=projPath & projFile, NewWindow:=False, HideSubtasks:=True, AttachToSources:=False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `Project.Name` or `Project.Fullname`

Comment: Project.Name returns the Filename and Fullname returns the full path with filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construct. This first item in the properties is Title.
activeproject.BuiltinDocumentProperties(1)

Comment: Side question: I can't find a list of what property is what in the BuiltinDocumentProperties do you have a link to documentation that has the list of properties and their associated indices?

Comment: mgrenier. To be honest, I stumbled unto the document properties a few years ago when I needed information just like you. I couldn't find any helpful definition so I used the old tried and true trial and error approach. You can create a simple macro to loop through all BuildInDocumentProperties and print them out but be sure to include an "on error resume next". In my case, the file has 34 properties but number 10 threw up an error. Most of the items are blank but they do follow lock step with the items in the Summary and Statistics tabs of document properties.

Comment: Thanks so much, silly that it wouldn't be clearly defined somewhere. Guess that would make our jobs to easy eh? lol. Thanks again.

Comment: mgrenier, there is probably documentation somewhere but trying to find it is another story. Maybe someone else will jump in with the "decoder ring"

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

```
ProjectObject.Title

ProjectObject.ProjectSummaryTask.Name

ProjectObject.Tasks.UniqueID(0).Name

ProjectObject.BuiltInDocumentProperties(1)

ProjectObject.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")
```

each of these will return the title of the project and can be used to set the title of the project. Note - ProjectObject is just the example variable name I'm using to represent a project object in code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask you the same question I asked the other person who answered, do you know of documentation that defines what all the built in document properties are?

Comment: @mgrenier this doesn't really show what they are but you can see what the object is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.builtindocumentproperties

It's basically all of the values you see in the Project Properties window (File --> Info --> Project Information --> Advanced Properties) except for the "Custom" tab

If you want to see yourself in code, try making a for loop to loop through all of the `BuiltInDocumentProperties` and print the name of each one

Comment: Kenny, you might want to read me comment below. Looping through all the BuilInDocumentProperties only gets you so far and it has a pitfall.

Comment: @john-project I'm not sure what pitfall you are referring to, this code works for me:

`Public Sub test()

    Dim prop As DocumentProperty
    
    For Each prop In ActiveProject.BuiltinDocumentProperties
        Debug.Print prop.Name
    Next prop

End Sub`

Comment: Kenny You are right, the code you show will list all 34 document properties. Where I hit an error is attempting to print out all 34 values of those properties. It fails on the "last print date", perhaps because I never print.

Comment: @john-project. I see. Yeah, Project can't actually access some of those values. I believe it's because the `BuiltInDocumentProperties` object is used across all of the Office apps. Some just don't apply to project like "Number of Paragraphs"

Comment: Kenny. Very helpful, thanks. I can skip over those properties that are not relevant to Project (there are several) and get a meaningful list. It just would be nice is MS explained this in the documentation.